# Find the max pair in a list of pairs in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Is there an easy way to find a max element from a list of pairs?  Base on the list  construction (these correspond to coordinates), there is a well defined max value {x_max, y_max}.  For example, I'm looking for a function `MaxElement`

```
MaxElement[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}}]
```

which will return `{1,1}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MaxElement[list_] := Module[{cases},
  cases = Cases[list, Max /@ Transpose[list]];
  If[cases == {}, "no clear maximum pair", First@cases]]

MaxElement[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}}]
```

> ```
> {1, 1}
> ```

```
MaxElement[{{0, 2}, {0, 1}, {2, 1}, {1, 0}}]
```

> ```
> no clear maximum pair
> ```

Comment: If I understood correctly, this finds the element wise (for x and y coordinates) max and checks whether this exists in the original list.

Comment: Yes, in case there isn't a well defined max value {x_max, y_max}.

Answer (score 5):

Or you could use the intrinsic function `MaximalBy`, something like

```
MaximalBy[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}}, Norm]
```

The second argument to `MaximalBy` is the function for determining which of two elements in the first argument is the maximal.  In this case it returns

```
{{1,1}}
```

If this rule doesn't separate all the elements, it returns all the maximal elements.  So

```
MaximalBy[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}}, Norm]
```

returns

```
{{0,1},{1,0}}
```

but the 3-argument form

```
MaximalBy[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}}, Norm, 1]
```

returns only the first maximal element found.

Comment: Just too many damn things to know to use Mathematica properly !

Comment: I find it too verbose, as if I'm writing Java code.